# ¿Como importar SQLAlchemy en un proyecto de flask modularizado con Blueprints?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Tengo un proyecto en flask modularizado de la siguiente manera

```
+ tienda-flask
|_ app
   |_ __init__.py
   |_ Models
      |_ __init__.py
      |_ Article.py
   |_ Article
      |_ __init__.py
      |_ routes.py
      |_ services.py
|_ main.py #entry point de mi app
```

Cuando registro mi blueprint me genera el siguiente error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'db' from partially initialized module 'app' (most likely due to a circular import) (/workspaces/tienda-flask/app/__init__.py)
```

Por lo que entiendo estoy haciendo una importacion circular, creo db desde `app/__init__.py` y luego lo importe en mi modelo `Article`, en mis archivo de `services.py` yo necesito llamar a mi modelo para pedirle una cosulta de base de datos pero como este archivo está importando `db` entonces es cuando genera el conflicto porque mi `services.py` se comunica con mi `routes.py` y este se comunica con `article/__init__.py` donde aqui creo el blueprint y finaliza comunicandose con `app/__init__.py` donde registro el blueprint y donde se encuentra `db = SQLAlchemy();`

**¿De que manera puedo solucionar este error? He buscado y no logro hayar una solución**

### `app/__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from os import environ

from .article import article_bp

db = SQLAlchemy();
migrate = Migrate();

def create_app() -> Flask:
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = environ.get('DB_CONNECTION')
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)

    #Blueprint register
    app.register_blueprint(article_bp) #cuando registro el blueprint genera un error de importacion circular

    return app
```

### `app/models/Article.py`

```
import datetime

from app import db

class Article(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'article'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    value = db.Column(db.String)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now)
    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now, onupdate=datetime.datetime.now)

    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
    
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'<Article {self.name}>'
    
    def getAll(self):
        return db.session.execute(self).scalars()
```

Answer (score 0):

Solucioné este problema manejando el mis extensiones desde un archivo externo y no desde el mismo archivo donde importo mis blueprints

cree el archivo `app/extensions.py`

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()
```

y en mi `app/__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from os import environ

from .extensions import (db, migrate)
from .article import article_bp



def create_app() -> Flask:
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = environ.get('DB_CONNECTION')
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)

    #Blueprint register
    app.register_blueprint(article_bp)

    return app
```